# Docker base image having telnet and ping

Tags: docker, redhat, ping, telnet

I have to debug network issues at a docker container. The container was built using "FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7/ubi-minimal"

It has no "telnet" or "ping" like a normal shell has. That was by design in order to save space.

I tried to install them through yum within docker container shell – yum is not available
They used something called “microdnf” which is like yum
Tried “bash-4.2# microdnf install iputils”  -  No package matches 'iputils'. Similar result for telnet

Tried running it inside the dockerfile, where the image is created. It seem to be getting installed – but image creation explodes"
“The command '/bin/sh -c yum install iputils' returned a non-zero code: 1”

I changed the image base from “FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7/ubi-minimal” to “FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7/ubi”
This has yum available.

“yum install iputils” from container shell, and from docker file failed the same way.

Is there an image (preferably redhat) that will let me use "ping" and will process my Dockerfile correctly?

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7/ubi-minimal

RUN microdnf update -y && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
RUN microdnf clean all
RUN microdnf install shadow-utils

# Create a group and user
RUN groupadd -r myapp && useradd -r myapp -g myapp
RUN useradd -r aspisc  -g myapp

RUN mkdir -p /opt/smyapp/config
RUN mkdir -p /opt/smyapp/logs
RUN chown -R myapp:smyapp /opt/myapp

RUN mkdir -p /opt/myapp/bin && mkdir -p /opt/myapp/libs

RUN mkdir -p /opt/jre/

ENV JAVA_LIBS_CP /opt/myapp/libs
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib64
RUN echo JAVA_LIBS_CP=${JAVA_LIBS_CP}


EXPOSE 9500
EXPOSE 9501

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "/opt/jre/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -cp /opt/smyapp/bin/*:$JAVA_LIBS_CP/*...."]
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that you have an error in your `chown` line, the above Dockerfile builds just fine, even if I add `iputils` to the microdnf install line. Moreover, I can ping from a running container, after having done so.

Comment: Why do you want to put these commands into Docker?  (Especially when they're both rather specialized tools – what does sending an ICMP packet to some destination prove? – and installed OOTB on most full Linux distributions?)

Comment: @DavidMaze When attempting to debug containerised applications/microservices, having basic networking utilities available is invaluable, just as the absence of 'vi' is infuriating. In kubernetes-land we can sidecar a busybox container into the pod. Not so simple in Docker. Is the docker network stack borked? Can I access the port I think I should be able to access? These are questions that need these tools to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the minimal base image (`registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7/ubi-minimal`). You can temporarily switch over to the non-minimal image (`registry.access.redhat.com/ubi7/ubi`) and install iputils there.

Comment: When I run that base image I can simply do `yum install iputils` and then use `ping`.

Comment: building image with yum iputils crushed.
This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Installing:
 iputils          x86_64          20160308-10.el7          ubi-7          148 k

Transaction Summary
==========================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 148 k
Installed size: 335 k

Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2020-05-30.19-51.hp0NDN.yumtx
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install iputils' returned a non-zero code: 1

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this one into ubi-minimal.
As mentioned before, you can add only the iputils package.

```
USER root
RUN microdnf update && microdnf install sudo iputils hostname findutils less nano && microdnf clean all
```

Yo need to set ROOT user to be able add yum folders, but it's very important to set another user later on, remove the sudo command or remove the whole commands before you deploy the container to production. You can have very important flaws in your environment other wise.

You can also consider further knowledge of the container. As stated in [Infinispan repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/infinispan/infinispan-images/11.0.x/README.md):

[ubi-minimal](https://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/ubi/) image.
Consequently, the image does not provide all of the tools that are commonly available in linux distributions.
Below is a list of common tools/recipes that are useful for debugging.

| Task | Command |
| --- | --- |
| Text editor | vi |
| Get the PID of the java process | ps -fC java |
| Get socket/file information | lsof |
| List all open files excluding network sockets | lsof |
| List all TCP sockets | ss -t -a |
| List all UDP sockets | ss -u -a |
| Network configuration | ip |
| Show unicast routes | ip route |
| Show multicast routes | ip maddress |

Answer (score 0):

You can install the utilities from the terminal and outside the container. It is the simpler solution that I found for this issue.

From your "host" machine running Docker.

```
docker exec -u 0 <container> bash -c "microdnf update && microdnf install sudo iputils hostname findutils less nano && microdnf clean all"
```

**Where**

- -u 0 stands for user ID=0 that is root account
- <> may be either the container ID or the container name